# A polynomial recovery problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, coding-theory

Suppose we know $deg(m(x))=n-1=deg(f_1(x))=deg(f_2(x))$.

Suppose we know $C_1(x),C_2(x)$ where $deg(C_i)=n$.

Then given $n$ values of $$C_1(x)(x+1)m(x) +C_1(x)(x+2)f_1(x)\in\Bbb F_q[x]$$ and $n$ values of $$C_2(x)(x+2)m(x) +C_2(x)(x+5)f_2(x)\in\Bbb F_q[x]$$ where $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ are unknown can we obtain any information about $m(x)$ so that if we have sufficiently many equations with different unknown $f_i(x)$ and known $C_i(x)$ we can recover $m(x)$?

$1,2,5$ are some arbitrary constants in above equations.

Comment: What do you mean by $n$ values?  Are you asking a probabilistic question: for a typical choice of $n$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$, does the restriction of the function to those values uniquely determine the polynomial?  Obviously if you are unlucky and your $n$ elements happen to equal the $n$ roots of $C(x)$, then you get no information about $m(x)$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr great question assume the $n$ values are definitely not roots of $C(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you gain no information about $m(x)$ whatsoever.

In fact, suppose we know
$$ A_{i,j} m(x_{i,j}) + B_{i,j} f_i (x_{i,j}) = y_{i,j}$$
for $i=1,2$ and $j=1, \ldots, n.$  Suppose we know $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ as well as $A_{i,j}$ and $B_{i,j}$.

If $m(x)$ is any arbitrary function, we can interpolate degree $n-1$ polynomials for $f_i$ that make these equations consistent.  Therefore, your equations actually don't say anything whatsoever about $m(x)$ no matter what $n$ points you evaluate at (and no matter what $C_i$ are doing).